# Configure project for Jasmine Test Case using Oracle Weblogic

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, weblogic

I am having a web based project which I deploy in weblogic server as EAR for execution. I need to implement Jasmine for unit testing.
I came to know that Jasmine can be executed in NodeJS server but my project has some servlets also as a part of it. So, how can I configure Jasmine to run on oracle weblogic server.

Also, if it is possible by any other means like integrating weblogic with NodeJS (I am not sure about this.) , kindly explain me the process to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to run your Jasmine tests from WebLogic.  That is like saying you want to run your JUnit tests on WebLogic.

JUnit tests are run from the command line in your development environment (often wrapped by the IDE) and also on your CI build agent.  Jasmine tests should follow the same pattern.   You shouldn't have to go through an entire deploy cycle just to run your unit tests.

I suggest looking at using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) to run your tests, both locally and on CI.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for sharing the info . Can you please explain me in detail how to configure and how does it is more convenient from Jasmine. Also, I am using Backbone JS for development and I don't know whether Karma supports Backbone JS.

Comment: You still write your tests in Jasmine, and yes you can write tests against Backbone with Jasmine.  Karma just provides a little bit of infrastructure around executing the tests.  The online documentation around Karma is very good and that plus Google should be enough to get you running.

Comment: I tried searching on google and I got help in setting up karma . 
Bu the problem here is my local weblogic server runs on port 7001 and on hitting the application, it hits a servlet which will execute a series of servlets and then redirect to html page. 

But nodeJS wont allow hitting the servlet directly as it is just a HTTP server.